# SQL performance of where exist over where in

Tags: sql

Having

```sql
create table Author
(
    id number primary key,
    name varchar(50)
);

create table Book
(
    id number primary key,
    title varchar(50),
    author_id number
);
```

Is there any performance difference between these 2 queries that give the same result?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM AUTHOR
WHERE ID IN (SELECT AUTHOR_ID FROM BOOK);

SELECT *
FROM AUTHOR A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BOOK B WHERE B.AUTHOR_ID = A.ID);
```

Of course in the where **IN** the subquery will be evaluated only once but  i think that the query with where **EXISTS** should run the subquery for **each** record of the root query. Do dbms make some sort of optimization? If yes, will the performance be the same in every case?

This is a basic example and maybe the dbms would be able to optimize it, but what happens if i call a stored function(plsql and others) into the subquery? What if the stored function body has allocation of variables, branches and other non-sql things?

-- EDIT

I'm working on oracle but I thought that this case was covered by most dbms.

As you suggested I run the EXPLAIN PLAN command and it gave the same result for both.

Comment: This varies substantially from database system to database system. But you can expect each DBMS to be able to `EXPLAIN`  a fullselect. Precede each of your query variants with the `EXPLAIN` keyword; the report will be the various steps the database goes through to find and retrieve your data. Compare them with each other. If you have difficulties to understand  - why don't you just run the two explains, and paste the result into your question? And, while you're at it, mention the DBMS variant: Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Vertica, PostgreSQL ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on DBMS and nothing is guaranteed. But assuming you use Oracle, it's smart enough to preselect the inner subquery for both given cases.

A performance equality is questionable, because in the latter case your DBMS would have to take all `AUTHOR.ID`s first, then find them in `BOOK` and only then filter some rows in `AUTHOR`, while the first one would just select all `BOOK.AUTHOR_ID` and then filter `AUTHOR` rows.

I would expect the first query to be a bit faster always.

As always optimizations are not the things you should rely on, especially when queries are not that obvious and may confuse the optimizer, so ideally you would find the exact optimization plans for both queries, compare them on your own or benchmark them.

Comment: Yeah I'm on oracle ^^ thx for the tips